# GCP Compute Engine limits download to 50 K/s?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, debian-based, google-cloud-networking

From some reason download traffic from virtual machine on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) with Debian 9 is limited to 50K/s? Upload seems to be fine, inline with my local upload link. 
It is the same with scp or https download. Any suggestions what might be wrong, where to search?

Machine type
n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)

CPU platform
Intel Skylake

Zone
europe-west4-a

Network interfaces
Premium tier

Thanks,
Mihaelus

Simple test:

```
wget https://hrcki.primasystems.si/Nova/assets/download.test.html
```

Output:

> --2018-10-18 15:21:00--  https://hrcki.primasystems.si/Nova/assets/download.test.html Resolving
>   hrcki.primasystems.si (hrcki.primasystems.si)... 35.204.252.248
>   Connecting to hrcki.primasystems.si
>   (hrcki.primasystems.si)|35.204.252.248|:443... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 541422592 (516M) [text/html]
>   Saving to: `download.test.html.1'  0% [] 1,073,152   **48.7K/s**  eta
>   2h 59m

Comment: Are you using proxy or VPN on your network? Can you try with another instance to compare the result? I created an instance with the mentioned specification and I did not faced any issues.

Comment: it's indeed slow, while the server might send as `text/html` instead `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I can confirm on a 10 Mbit link that the downloads are between 15Kbit and 20Kbit to Seattle. This is not normal with an N1-standard-1 instance for a binary file download. I am interested in learning about the solution to this performance issue.

Comment: I am not using VPN. It is easy to repeat from other places. First month speed was good, now it is limited. Other instances are OK. CPU load is small around 10%.

Comment: Most likely the link between endpoint and Google is the problem, I recommend you to try to download something from a known source and compare the result. There is no issues on the GCE or the Google network.

Comment: Hello Milad, i do not think so, we use different endpoints.  John Hanley has repeated it (as I did too) from different continent. Thanks anyway for the idea.

Comment: Try to download a test with other source, such as:   wget --output-document=/dev/nullhttp://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip and try a [none custom instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) on different region.

Comment: Hello Milad, thanks for your comments. Your test results are as expected: 2019-03-06 10:57:28 (1.93 MB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [524288000/524288000]

Answer (score 0):

Always good to minimize variables when trying to diagnose.  So while it is unlikely the use of HTTP is why things are that very slow, you might consider using netperf or iperf3 to measure TCP bulk transfer performance between your VM in GCP and your local system.  You can do that either "by hand" or via PerfKit Benchmarker https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/perfkit-benchmarker-for-evaluating-cloud-network-performance

It can be helpful to have packet traces - from both ends when possible - to look at.  You want the packet traces to be started before the test - it is important to see the packets used to establish the TCP connection(s).  They do not need to be "full packet" traces, and often you don't want them to be.  Capturing just the first 96 bytes of each packet would be sufficient for this sort of investigating.

You might also consider taking snapshots of the network statistics offered by the OSes running in your GCP VM and local system.  For example, if running *nix taking a snapshot of "netstat -s" before and after the test.  And perhaps a traceroute from each end towards the other.

Network statistics and packet traces, along with as many details about the two endpoints as possible are among the sorts of things support organizations are likely to request when looking to help resolve an issue of this sort.